# Application-modal MessageBox from non-modal WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, modal-dialog, messagebox

I work on an application that contains a mixture of Winforms and WPF. The older parts of the app are Winforms (including the "main" application window) with some of the more recent screens being WPF. These WPF windows are typically not launched modally, as the user will often be working simultaneously on different screens.

If the user encounters a warning/error as a result of a particular action on any of the WPF screens, they will usually be notified by a WPF MessageBox (System.Windows.MessageBox). Is there a way to make those message boxes modal at the application level, rather than at the level of the particular screen that launched it? I want to force the user to acknowledge the warning before interacting with the other screens.

Using a System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox seems to work instead seems to work but I would like to stick with the System.Windows.MessageBox. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with this in WPF. You just should specify Window **owner** parameter to your MessageBox.Show invokation. Owned message boxes are modal by their nature. For example, use this overloaded version of Show to customize you message box:

```
public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon);
```

Here is very simple (although surely working :)) example:

*MainWindow.xaml:*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2_ModalMessageBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Click="Button_Click">Modal</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs:*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Text", "Caption", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
}
```

Comment: For that to work the main window "owner" would have to be WPF. The issue here is that I have a Winform main window, a secondary WPF screen (that is not launched modally), and when a WPF messagebox is shown from the WPF screen it is only modal to the WPF window, not the entire application.